# codeigniter gas ORM arrays not working, what am I missing

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm

I just started learning codeigniter and gas ORM, I am kinda confused about writing models, in the model I have

```
<?php
namespace Model;
use \Gas\Core;
use \Gas\ORM;
class Salary extends ORM {

    public $foreign_key = array(
        '\\model\\Users' => 'user_id',
        '\\model\\Salary' =>'salary_id'
    );

    function _init() {
        self::$fields = array(
            'salary' => ORM::field('int[11]'),
            'user_id'=> ORM::field('int[11]')
        );
    }
}
```

in the controller I have,

```
$data['c_users'] = Model\Salary::find_by_user_id('734990771');
```

in the view,

```
foreach ($c_users as $key => $value) {
                echo $c_users->salary;
            }
```

I get "Trying to get property of non-object" error, when i did a var_dump it shows details about the model and also the search results. What am I missing here?

Comment: tried but not working,

Comment: var_dump key and value and what do you get?

Comment: "Trying to get property of non-object" and a NULL

Comment: In your error message does it say the problem is with controller or view or with model?

Comment: error is on the view, in the backtrace it says the error is on error handler and line of viaw loading

Answer (score 0):

In your loop try

```
foreach ($c_users as $key => $value) {
                echo $value; // or $value->something

            }
```

or
      if `$c_users` is not multidimensional array

```
$c_users->salary
```

Comment: it says undefined variable

Comment: $this->load->view('users/salary', $data);